# ArgumentCountError - Too few arguments

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

I am just learning codeigniter and I have a page to update my database. but I get an error like this:

> Type: ArgumentCountError
>
> Message: Too few arguments to function Inhouse::ubah(), 0 passed in D:\xampp\htdocs\slc\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 1 expected
>
> Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\slc\application\controllers\Inhouse.php
>
> Line Number: 120

How can I fix this problem? This is my code:

---

Controller :

```
public function ubah($id)
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Change Form - Data IHT Program';
        $data['inhouse'] = $this->Inhouse_model->getInhouseById($id);
        $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array();

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('subtitle', 'Subtitle', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('overview', 'Overview', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('goals', 'Goals', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('agenda1', 'Agenda 01', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('agenda2', 'Agenda 02', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('agenda3', 'Agenda 03', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('agenda4', 'Agenda 04', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('agenda5', 'Agenda 05', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('agenda6', 'Agenda 06', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('agenda7', 'Agenda 07', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('agenda8', 'Agenda 08', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('trainer', 'Trainer', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            if (!$this->session->userdata('email')) {
                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            } else {
                $this->load->view('templates/login_header', $data);
            }
            $this->load->view('inhouse/ubah', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        } else {
            // cek jika ada gampar yg diupload
            $upload_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];

            if ($upload_image) {
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = '5048';
                $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/inhouse/';

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ($this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
                    $old_image = $data['inhouse']['image'];
                    if ($old_image != 'default.jpg') {
                        unlink(FCPATH . 'assets/img/inhouse/' . $old_image);
                    } else {
                        $new_image = $this->upload->data('file_name');
                        $this->db->set('image', $new_image);
                    }
                } else {
                    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                }
            }

            $this->db->set('image', $new_image);
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $this->db->update('inhouse', $data);

            $this->Inhouse_model->ubahInhouseProgram();
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash', 'Diubah!');
            redirect('admin/product');
        }
    }
```

Model :

```
public function ubahInhouseProgram()
    {
        $data = [
            "image" => $this->input->post('image', true),
            "title" => $this->input->post('title', true),
            "subtitle" => $this->input->post('subtitle', true),
            "overview" => $this->input->post('overview', true),
            "goals" => $this->input->post('goals', true),
            "agenda1" => $this->input->post('agenda1', true),
            "agenda2" => $this->input->post('agenda2', true),
            "agenda3" => $this->input->post('agenda3', true),
            "agenda4" => $this->input->post('agenda4', true),
            "agenda5" => $this->input->post('agenda5', true),
            "agenda6" => $this->input->post('agenda6', true),
            "agenda7" => $this->input->post('agenda7', true),
            "agenda8" => $this->input->post('agenda8', true),
            "trainer" => $this->input->post('trainer', true)
        ];
        $this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('id'));
        $this->db->update('inhouse', $data);
    }
```

View :

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row mt-5 mb-5">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

            <!-- FORM -->
            <div class="card myshadow">
                <div class="card-header font-weight-bold">
                    <h2>Change Form Data IHT Program</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">


                    <?= form_open_multipart('inhouse/ubah'); ?>

                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $inhouse['id']; ?>">


                    <div class="form-group mt-4">
                        <div class="">Picture</div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <img src="<?= base_url('assets/img/inhouse/') . $inhouse['image']; ?>" class="img-thumbnail">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="custom-file">
                                    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="image" name="image">
                                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="image">Choose file</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group mt-4">
                        <label for="title">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" value="<?= $inhouse['title'] ?>">
                        <small class="form-text text-danger"><?= form_error('title') ?></small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group mt-4">
                        <label for="subtitle">Subtitle</label>
                        <textarea type="text" name="subtitle" class="form-control" id="subtitle" rows="3"><?= $inhouse['subtitle']; ?></textarea>
                        <small class="form-text text-danger"><?= form_error('subtitle') ?></small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group mt-4">
                        <label for="overview">Overview</label>
                        <textarea type="text" name="overview" class="form-control" id="overview" rows="8"><?= $inhouse['overview'] ?></textarea>
                        <small class="form-text text-danger"><?= form_error('overview') ?></small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group mt-4">
                        <label for="goals">Goals</label>
                        <textarea type="text" name="goals" class="form-control" id="goals" rows="3"><?= $inhouse['goals'] ?></textarea>
                        <small class="form-text text-danger"><?= form_error('goals') ?></small>
                    </div>

                    <hr class="mt-5">

                    <div class="form-group mt-4">
                        <label for="agenda1">Agenda 01</label>
                        <input type="text" name="agenda1" class="form-control" id="agenda1" value="<?= $inhouse['agenda1'] ?>">
                        <small class="form-text text-danger"><?= form_error('agenda1') ?></small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group mt-4">
                        <label for="agenda2">Agenda 02</label>
                        <input type="text" name="agenda2" class="form-control" id="agenda2" value="<?= $inhouse['agenda2'] ?>">
                        <small class="form-text text-danger"><?= form_error('agenda2') ?></small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group mt-4">
                        <label for="agenda3">Agenda 03</label>
                        <input type="text" name="agenda3" class="form-control" id="agenda3" value="<?= $inhouse['agenda3'] ?>">
                        <small class="form-text text-danger"><?= form_error('agenda3') ?></small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group mt-4">
                        <label for="agenda4">Agenda 04</label>
                        <input type="text" name="agenda4" class="form-control" id="agenda4" value="<?= $inhouse['agenda4'] ?>">
                        <small class="form-text text-danger"><?= form_error('agenda4') ?></small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group mt-4">
                        <label for="agenda5">Agenda 05</label>
                        <input type="text" name="agenda5" class="form-control" id="agenda5" value="<?= $inhouse['agenda5'] ?>">
                        <small class="form-text text-danger"><?= form_error('agenda5') ?></small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group mt-4">
                        <label for="agenda6">Agenda 06</label>
                        <input type="text" name="agenda6" class="form-control" id="agenda6" value="<?= $inhouse['agenda6'] ?>">
                        <small class="form-text text-danger"><?= form_error('agenda6') ?></small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group mt-4">
                        <label for="agenda7">Agenda 07</label>
                        <input type="text" name="agenda7" class="form-control" id="agenda7" value="<?= $inhouse['agenda7'] ?>">
                        <small class="form-text text-danger"><?= form_error('agenda7') ?></small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group mt-4">
                        <label for="agenda8">Agenda 08</label>
                        <input type="text" name="agenda8" class="form-control" id="agenda8" value="<?= $inhouse['agenda8'] ?>">
                        <small class="form-text text-danger"><?= form_error('agenda8') ?></small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group mt-4">
                        <label for="trainer">Trainer</label>
                        <input type="text" name="trainer" class="form-control" id="trainer" value="<?= $inhouse['trainer'] ?>">
                        <small class="form-text text-danger"><?= form_error('trainer') ?></small>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" name="ubah" class="btn btn-primary mt-5">Change Data</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END FORM -->

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What does your route definition look like?

Answer (score 0):

Get Argument like this "$this->uri->segment(2)"

exp:- htts://localhost/ci/50/60

$this->uri->segment(2) // O/P 50

$this->uri->segment(3) // O/P 60

for more information go here [Segments](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html)

```
public function ubah(){
 $this->uri->segment(2);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, after reading Codeigniter's documentation I still don't quite understand, my code still can't be run ... if you don't mind, can you explain in more detail? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I guess , this error occurs only when you try to access to controler without arguments like

```
http://localhost/slc/index.php/ubah
```

If you access the controler like following , there shouldn't be an error

```
http://localhost/slc/index.php/ubah/2
```

You can fix this by setting a default value to `$id`

```
public function ubah($id = -1){
    if($id != -1){
         //put your code here
    }else{
        show_404();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your answers, i really appreciate you guys for helping me to fix my code.. 
but, i just removing the "action" from my form_opener_multipart();

From this :

```
<?= form_open_multipart('inhouse/ubah'); ?>
```

Into this :

```
<?= form_open_multipart(); ?>
```

I do not really understand why it can be like that, but now my program can be run, can you guys explain to me? i'll really appreciate that.

And there is another problem, the other column of my database table can be updated except "the image" column.